# Vite not working well with React-Router-Dom on deployed build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, vite, netlify

```
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { SnackbarProvider } from "notistack";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { auth, fTeacher, sTeacher, student, admin } from "./features/selectors";
import { routes } from "./constants";

import UserHeader from "./components/UserHeader";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import Loader from "./components/Loader";

import Admin from "./pages/Admin/Admin";
import Auth from "./pages/Auth/Auth";
import FormTeacher from "./pages/FormTeacher/FormTeacher";
import SubTeacher from "./pages/SubjectTeacher/SubTeacher";
import Student from "./pages/Student/Student";

import { Container } from "reactstrap";

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const { isAuthLoading } = useSelector(auth);
  const { isAdminLoading } = useSelector(admin);
  const { isStudentLoading } = useSelector(student);
  const { isFTeacherLoading } = useSelector(fTeacher);
  const { isSTeacherLoading } = useSelector(sTeacher);

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        {isAuthLoading ||
        isLoading ||
        isAdminLoading ||
        isStudentLoading ||
        isFTeacherLoading ||
        isSTeacherLoading ? (
          <Loader />
        ) : (
          ""
        )}

        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Auth />} />
          <Route
            path="/admin/*"
            element={
              <div>
                <Sidebar />
                <div className="main-content">
                  <UserHeader />
                  <Container>
                    <Admin setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />
                  </Container>
                </div>
              </div>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/form-teacher/*"
            element={
              <div>
                <Sidebar />
                <div className="main-content">
                  <UserHeader />
                  <Container>
                    <FormTeacher setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />
                  </Container>
                </div>
              </div>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/sub-teacher/*"
            element={
              <div>
                <Sidebar />
                <div className="main-content">
                  <UserHeader />
                  <Container>
                    <SubTeacher setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />
                  </Container>
                </div>
              </div>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="/student/*"
            element={
              <div>
                <Sidebar />
                <div className="main-content">
                  <UserHeader />
                  <Container>
                    <Student setIsLoading={setIsLoading} />
                  </Container>
                </div>
              </div>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <SnackbarProvider
        anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: "center", vertical: "bottom" }}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have this app and everything works well on `"localhost:5173"`
If I directly go to a url like `"http://localhost:5173/admin/result"`, it goes directly to the specific component. But when I deploy the build version of the application and go to the new url `"https://smsystem.netlify.app/admin/result"`, Netlify throws a 404 not found error. If I navigate within the app it works well, I just can't go to the url directly.

Comment: this is not a problem with vite nor your routing system. if you are using nginx make sure to add a fallback to `index.html` for not found routes. I don't really know the flow of netlify deployment but there must be an option to do this.

Comment: But the route in question is actually a working route, but it throws a 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to CRA deployment documentation, for [Netlify](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#netlify) you create a redirect file to return your root index.html file for all page requests into the app.

Create a `public/_redirects` file with the following content:

```
/*  /index.html  200
```

The build process should copy the `"/public"` directory to the build output.