# React Routes work on localhost but gives 404 on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-router

I'm using React Routes this is what I wrote which works on LocalHost whether I directly go to *`localhost:3000`* or *`localhost/home`*

But on the main server (using netlify to host) and custom domain
When I enter *`localhost/home`*, it gives me ***Error 404***

```
return (
    <div className={App ${isIntroIn ? 'intro-in' : ''} ${isPreOut ? 'pre-out' : ''}}>
      
      {!isIntroIn && <Preload isPreOut={isPreOut} />}
      {isPreOut && <Navigate to="/home" replace />}
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Intro isIntroIn={isIntroIn} isPreOut={isPreOut} />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77098959/8690857